# How to keep user signed in after the browser has been closed and 24 hours has expired in SPA (ADB2C)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Currently Azure AD B2C issues a refresh token that is valid for 24 hours (non-configurable, non-renewable) for single page apps that use the PKCE code flow.

When that 24 hours is expired from the initial sign in the user needs to reauthenticate with the AD B2C. If the browser has been closed during that time the AD B2C session is lost and now user must interactively reauthenticate. I don't understand how this could be acceptable default user experience for most web apps.

Is there any way to work around this? Perhaps a way to make the AD B2C session persistent so that it survives browser closes and full interactive reauthentication is avoided. I don't want to have the only web app in the universe that requires the user to sign in again every 24 hours.

Edit:
We're using external identity providers so [KMSI for local accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#enable-keep-me-signed-in-kmsi) doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **keep me signed in** to extend the users Azure AD B2C session lifetime.

**Please Refer:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in

**Update:**

The Azure AD B2C Session Cookie will always be evaluated first to determine if the user should be sent back to their federated IdP to do a new authentication. Only when both the Azure AD B2C session cookie **and** the federated IdPs session cookie are expired, will the user have to re-enter their credentials at the federated IdP.

To prevent the user having to go back to the federated IdP to authenticate, you can raise the AAD B2C session cookie lifetime beyond that of the federated IdP session cookie lifetime.

When using Custom Policy, you can use the Session Management technical profile to make sure the federated IdP authentication is part of the session itself.

See how we did this for the Google IdP with the use of SM-SocialLogin:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-goog-idp#add-a-claims-provider

`<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />`

Add this line to the federated IdP technical profile to make sure its part of the AAD B2C session.

Once you are app is closed you may need to login again, because your app cookes is not persisted.

You could maintain a cookie set by the app to automatically send the user via the login endpoint if they had signed in previously with KMSI. You can use a claims resolver to send the KMSI claim into the token so your app can understand the user logged in with KMSI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview

SessionExpiryType/SessionExpiryInSeconds - not related to KMSI cookie. Relates to B2Cs normal SSO Cookie.

KeepAliveInDays - KMSI Cookie lifetime.

Please see this document for more clear information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty#userjourneybehaviors

Comment: We're using external identity providers. As far as I can understand KMSI only works with local accounts.

Comment: Hi @JuhoHanhimäki,KMSI won't work for External Idp's. Please check my updated answer which will help for this scenario

Comment: "To prevent the user having to go back to the federated IdP to authenticate, you can raise the AAD B2C session cookie lifetime beyond that of the federated IdP session cookie lifetime."

Per documentation the max session lifetime is 720 minutes. I don't think documentation is correct. Isn't the limit 1440 minutes or 24 hours? Either way that's 24 hour limit after which the user is required to choose the IdP again which is bad user experience.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior

Comment: For custom policies the max SessionExpiryInSeconds seems to be 7 days. It's not great, but still better than 24 hours.

Comment: One of my concerns about this session is its persistence. Does it persist if browser is closed? I have a feeling the session is lost as soon as the browser is closed which makes it useless. But i guess I'll have to continue investigation. The simple ask: keep user signed in seems overly complicated to achieve in B2C.

Comment: When you refer to KMSI: "KeepAliveInDays - KMSI Cookie lifetime." Does that apply to social identity providers too or only to the local accounts? Local accounts are not main concern for me right now. As I understand KMSI has nothing to do with social identity providers and what matters instead is the B2C session (controlled by the "SessionExpiryInSeconds") so the B2C automatically authenticates with the same IdP that user initially signed in with.

Comment: "Once you are app is closed you may need to login again, because your app cookes is not persisted." My app login session is stored in browser local storage so it survives browser closes. Issue is that after 24 hours the refresh token is not valid anymore and B2C forces user to choose IdP again (instead of remembering the IdP and reauthenticating automatically).

Comment: I did test the KMSI with local accounts. It works great. I can close the browser, delete the application session and B2C still remembers the local account (and automatically signs in). But the problem still exists with social IdPs. B2C does not remember the social IdP selection after the browser has been closed and shows user the B2C sign in prompt.